# page.php overrides custom page template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't get rid of a right sidebar in a custom page template. Something seems to be passing from page.php to the custom page template and I don't know how to prevent this. The custom page template code is simple:

```
 <?php
/* Template Name: sample template */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="body">
    <?php the_content(); ?>


<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Below is my page.php code, inherited from a previous developer:

```
   <?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="body">
<div class="align left">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<br />
<?php the_title(); ?>
  <br />
  <?php // include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>
  <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="entry">

      <?php the_content(); ?>
          <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' =>'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

  </div>
      <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>

    </div>

    <?php // comments_template(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="align right">
    <?php
    global $post;
    $showImage = true;
    $url = $url = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/uploads/';
    $file = get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), '_wp_attached_file', true);
    if ( $file == ''){
        $showImage = false;
    }
    $url .= $file;
    if ( $showImage ){
        ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="" />
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I don't want to edit page.php to get a full-width custom page. How can I achieve this in the custom page template?

Comment: Have you checked if `get_sidebar()` is called in the footer or header file?

Comment: get_sidebar is not called - if you look at the code above, the div class="align right" (which has a set width in css), is called on page.php and filled with an image if attached to the post. The problem is I can't exclude that div from my custom page template.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `get_sidebar();` function.

you can know more about this function  here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar

Comment: He wants to remove a sidebar, not add one